# Parsing mathematical expressions with two values that have parentheses and minus signs

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to parse equations like the ones below, which only have two values or the square root of a certain value, from a text file:

```
100+100

-100-100

-(100)+(-100)

sqrt(100)
```

by the minus signs, parentheses and the operator symbol in the middle and the square root, and I have no idea how to start off... I've got the file part done and the simple calculation parts except that I couldnt get my program to solve the equations in the above.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255], sym,sym2,del1,del2,del3,del4;
    double num1, num2;
    int ret;
    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");

    while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp)!=NULL){
        char *tok = buff;
        sscanf(tok,"%lf%c%lf",&num1,&sym,&num2);

        switch(sym){
            case '+': printf("%lf\n", num1+num2);
                    break;
            case '-': printf("%lf\n", num1-num2);
                    break;
            case '*': printf("%lf\n", num1*num2);
                    break;
            case '/': printf("%lf\n", num1/num2);
                    break;
            default: printf("The input value is not correct\n");
                    break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

That is what I have written for the other basic operations without parentheses and the minus sign for the second value and it works great for the simple ones. I'm using a switch statement to calculate the add, sub, mul and div operations but I'm not sure how to properly use the `sscanf` function (if I am not using it properly) or if there is another way, such as using a function like `strtok` to properly parse the parentheses and the minus signs. Any kind help?

Comment: did you try a search for "parsing infix expressions" or "shunting yard algorithm"?

Comment: Do you have to write this from scratch? or can you use something like flex and bison (or antlr) to generate a grammar for you?

Comment: i have thought about infix expressions and shunting yard algorithm, but i thought it would have been alot more simpler...i'll have a look at it again thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Parsing expressions, with parentheses and unequal operator precedence, is THE standard parsing example in just about every compiler textbook in existence.  Function calls aren't USUALLY part of that example, but they are simple enough to add.  Rather than go trial-and-error, your life will be a lot easier in the long run if you learn how to do it for real.

The most accessible introduction to building hand-constructed parsers I have seen is Jack Crenshaw's ["Let's Build A Compiler"](http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/compiler.pdf).

The most accessible textbook I've seen on compiler construction is Wirth's ["Compiler Construction"](http://www.ethoberon.ethz.ch/WirthPubl/CBEAll.pdf).  It describes hand-coded recursive descent parsing.

The canonical references on compiler construction are the [various Dragon Books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book).  I personally used the [Green Dragon Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201000229) and found it usable, although the focus is on mechanically-generated LALR parsers rather than hand-coded parsers.

Comment: Good answer. I thought questions like this are supposed to test some typical algorithmic knowledge and technique, but it turns out this is in the specialized area of compilers, not general domain. Can you give a possible answer as to how much a software developer should know in this area. I am not specialized at all in compiler, but I would like to know how much basic knowledge in this area that any software developer needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach
There are many ways to parse and evaluate expressions as a recursive data structure.
Any expression can be defined as following:

expression -> term + term - term

term -> factor*factor/factor
factor -> variabler، number، expression as 10 +5*B consist of 2 terms 10، 5*B.

Second term contains 2 factors 5 and B.

Here is a sequence you will follow

1. input an expression as 9/3-(100 5)
2. the parser gets the first term 9/3.
3. get each factor and divide the integers the result is 3
4. get the second term term (100 56). Start recursively analysing the second sub expression.
5. get each terms and add them. The result is 156:
   return from the recursive call, 3-156 =3.

This is complex concept that takes time to get used to.

If you want an example tell me. (I didn't give example because it will be very long). But if you want an example I will happily give you one).

If you feel confused you can google " recursive expression parsing".

Answer (score 0):

You should build **AST(Abstract Syntax Tree)**. Build it with respect for precedence so multiplication/division comes first before subtraction or addition. Parentheses also should be handled but that only sound complex in theory.

[My simple parser I wrote some time ago](https://github.com/LukasPukenis/minilang/blob/master/Source.c)

As you can see from the source code I am using templates. Just simple linked lists which let me distinguish input such as `VALUE OPERATION VALUE`(1+2 or 3*6).

When I meet parentheses like `1+2*(4+5)` only `1+2` and `4+5` matches a template, so I reduce them and I have `VAL*(VAL)`. Now `OPEN_PAREN VALUE CLOSE_PAREN)` matches a template and so I reduce it into `VAL`. Now I have `VAL*VAL`. And that's all.

The source code was written for learning purposes by me so I tried to keep it clean and small. In case you need an explanation, feel free to ask in the comments.